About building Network Extension
I tried to add Network Extension to the Telegram project and link an xcframework and additional data files, but it was not successful. How should I write the BUILD file of this Network Extension?
I tried using ios_extension to add Network Extension and xcframework_import to add xcframework. Here are the rules I added xcframework and Network Extension:
ios_extension(
    name = "NetWorkTunnel",
    bundle_id = "{telegram_bundle_id}.NetWorkTunnel".format(
        telegram_bundle_id = telegram_bundle_id,
    ),
    families = [
        "iphone",
        "ipad",
    ],
    infoplists = [
        ":NetWorkInfoPlist",
        ":VersionInfoPlist",
        ":RequiredDeviceCapabilitiesPlist",
        ":BuildNumberInfoPlist",
        ":AppNameInfoPlist",
    ],
    provisioning_profile = select({
        ":disableProvisioningProfilesSetting": None,
        "//conditions:default": "@build_configuration//provisioning:NetWorkTunnel.mobileprovision",
    }),
    minimum_os_version = minimum_os_version,
    sdk_frameworks = [
        "Foundation",
        "NetworkExtension",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//Telegram/NetWorkTunnel:NetWorkLib",
    ],
)

load(
    "@build_bazel_rules_apple//apple:apple.bzl",
    "apple_static_xcframework_import"
)

apple_static_xcframework_import(
    name = "Mdxo",
    xcframework_imports = glob([
        "NetWorkTunnel/Mdx.xcframework/**",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

